# In Meteor, how can I write a helper to use in the handlebar's each loop?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Each row of my Accounts (a collection) is about {_id: xxx, last_name:'kuo', first_name'willy'}

I have following in my client.js

```
Template.accountPage.accounts = function() {
    return Accounts.find({});
}
```

My question is in my client.html:

```
{{#each accounts}}

  {{last_name}}
  {{first_name}}
  {{full_name}}   # <-----  how can I implement the full_name helper
                  #         which should return account.first_name + account.last_name

{{/each}}
```

### EDIT

Above example should be simple, following is the new one:

I have following in my client.js

```
Template.accountPage.accounts = function() {
    return Accounts.find({});
}
```

My question is in my client.html:

```
{{#each accounts}}

  {{last_name}}
  {{first_name}}
  {{created_at}}   # <-----  how can I implement the created_at
                   #         which is computed by accounts._id.getTimestamp()

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defined the following helper can achieve the goal:

```
Template.accountPage.helpers({
    created_at: function() {
        return this._id.getTimestamp();
    }
})
```

Comment: To use this its `{{created_at created_at}}` yes?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, no need to pass any parameter, use {{created_at}} directly.

Answer (score 1):

waitingkuops method works, but only on that specific case. If you want to assign arbitrary helpers to looped items, you do something like this:

```
{{#each accounts}}
  {{> accountItem}}
{{/each}}

<template name="accountItem">
  // custom helper
  {{customValue}}
  // standard values
  {{last_name}}
  {{first_name}}
  {{last_name}}
</template>

Template.accountItem.helpers({
  customValue: this.first_name + this.last_name + 'hey!'
});
```

Comment: And if you need to pass an argument to the `{{> accountItem passThisArg}}` will then be available in the helpers `customValue: function(){ thisVal = 'This is the passed argument:'+this; return thisVal; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{#each accounts}}
  {{last_name}}
  {{first_name}}
  {{first_name}} {{last_name}} 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a helper that I can keep the html simple.

Comment: Why are you looking for a helper function when you already have all the data you need? Is there a more complex example you are worried about?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that! I would suggest try to actually store that data in accounts so that you can just call {{created_at}} like your example.

Comment: I've just found the way to achieve my goal, any way, thanks for your advice.